# Parecelable with children

Tags: java, android, parcelable

I've been reading on this matter but I have not found a solution yet.

I want to use the method `onSavedInstance` to save an array of objects with the type Cell but all the objects inside the array will be children of Cell. My main problem is that I am not sure where to put my `public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyObject> CREATOR`.

#### Parent:

```
public abstract class Cell implements Parcelable{
    protected final int x;
    protected final int y;
    protected int conetion;

    ...

}
```

#### Children:

Frist:

```
public class Block extends Cell {
    private final Paint paint;

    ...

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
        out.writeInt(describeContents());
        out.writeInt(this.x);
        out.writeInt(this.y);
    }
}
```

Second:

```
public class Path extends Cell {

    private final Paint paint;
    private final boolean orientation;
    private Type conected;
    private int count;

    ...

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
        out.writeInt(describeContents());
        out.writeInt(this.x);
        out.writeInt(this.y);
        out.writeInt(this.conected.getColor());
        out.writeInt(this.conetion);
        out.writeInt(this.count);
    }   
}
```

Third:

```
public class Dot extends Cell {

    private final Paint paint;
    private Type conected;
    private int count;

    ...

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
        out.writeInt(describeContents());
        out.writeInt(this.x);
        out.writeInt(this.y);
        out.writeInt(this.conected.getColor());
        out.writeInt(this.conetion);
        out.writeInt(this.count);
    }
}
```

Fourth:

```
public class Path extends Cell {

    private final Paint paint;
    private final boolean orientation;
    private Type conected;
    private int count;

    ...

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
        out.writeInt(describeContents());
        out.writeInt(this.x);
        out.writeInt(this.y);
        out.writeInt(this.conected.getColor());
        out.writeInt(this.conetion);
        out.writeInt(this.count);
    }   
}
```

Thank you all for your time.

Carlos Morgado

Comment: You need to make every class in the container and the container itself Parcelable, and http://parcelabler.com can automatically do that for you.

Comment: Yes I know I need to implement Parecelable, but my point is where do I put `public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyObject> CREATOR`? Do I put it in every type, or only int the parent? and how depending on the ´describeContents()´ does it recreate the array after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your `describeContents()` method should always return `0` unless you're using a `FileDescriptor` (which is a very unusual case).

Secondly, since your base class is abstract, you won't need a CREATOR instance for it. However, you still do need to save/restore data from it. For a simple example, take two classes, `BaseParcelable` and `ParcelableImpl`, where `BaseParcelable` is the abstract base class, and `ParcelableImpl` is a subclass with extra data:

```
abstract class BaseParcelable implements Parcelable {
    private int mX;
    private int mY;

    protected BaseParcelable(int x, int y) {
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }

    // Provide a protected constructor that subclasses can call
    // through to initialize all of the saved base class info
    protected BaseParcelable(Parcel in) {
        mX = in.readInt();
        mY = in.readInt();
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
        // Write out any info in this base class. No CREATOR
        // needs to be provided for this class since it is not
        // instantiable.
        parcel.writeInt(mX);
        parcel.writeInt(mY);
    }
}
```

And then `ParcelableImpl`:

```
public final class ParcelableImpl extends BaseParcelable {
    private int mZ;

    public ParcelableImpl(int x, int y, int z) {
        super(x, y);
        mZ = z;
    }

    // Have a constructor taking a parcel that you can use
    // to pass the parcel to the superclass
    private ParcelableImpl(Parcel in) {
        super(in);
        mZ = in.readInt();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
        // Make sure to call through to super so that BaseParcelable
        // writes out its data first, then write additional data 
        // specific to this class implementation
        super.writeToParcel(parcel, i);
        parcel.writeInt(mZ);
    }

    // This class *does* need a creator since it's an instantiable class
    public static final Creator<ParcelableImpl> CREATOR = new Creator<ParcelableImpl>() {
        @Override
        public ParcelableImpl createFromParcel(Parcel parcel) {
            // Pass the Parcel into your Parcel constructor
            return new ParcelableImpl(parcel);
        }

        @Override
        public ParcelableImpl[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ParcelableImpl[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Ok so I got part of it and in my case how will it work with four children?

Comment: Each child works just like ParcelableImpl. They all have their own CREATOR. Just think of it as a static factory method.

Comment: So the Parcel will know what type it should be?

Comment: Yup, it actually just uses reflection to look at the object's class, and find a static public field called CREATOR.

Answer (score 0):

I think this way:
If you have a member variable that is not inherited from the parent then your child Parecelable constructor implementation is different from the parent and so the function inside your creator

```
public MyParcelable createFromParcel(Parcel in)
```

must return your child with specific constructor for it.

Other cases that you just override some functions from your parent I think you can declare it inside your parent.

Comment: I can be wrong but from what I read the `public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyObject> CREATOR` was what called that constructor so my doubt remains...

Comment: Yes you are right : the function public MyParcelable createFromParcel(Parcel in) must return your object so must call return new object(), so if it has a  member variable that is not in its parent object can not be parent and you must return new child() other wise I think it can.